# Identify parentheses in lambda expression with ExpressionVisitor in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expressionvisitor

I have a library that converts a lambda expression to an odata filter string using the `ExpressionVisitor` class.
For example, the expression `o => o.Teste == null && !(o.Date != DateTime.Now)` turns into `$filter=Teste eq null and not(Date ne xx/xx/xx)`

It works fine. The problem is when I have to group parts of the condition with parentheses (). The parentheses are ignored and it just writes the condition without it.
For example, the expression `(o => o.Name != null && o.Name == "Joe") || !(o.Date != DateTime.Now)` turns into `$filter=Name ne null and Name eq 'Joe' or not(Date ne xx/xx/xx)`

What's weird is that the `ExpessionVisitor` doesn't seem to identify the parentheses, it has a `NodeType` for not `!(expression)` but it doesn't have for `(expression)`.

I've been searching for this on Google for two days and I can't seem to find an answer.

Thanks in advance for the Help.

Answer (score 3):

The node type for not isn't for `!(expression)` it's just for `!expression` - the parentheses aren't part of it.

Parentheses are necessary in source code to indicate the precedence you want. They're not necessary in expression trees because the precedence is inherent in the tree.

If you don't mind sometimes having extra parentheses, you could just make your string conversion *always* include them. So every time you have an OR or and AND expression with operand expressions `x` and `y`, just turn that into `(x || y)` or `(x && y)`, unconditionally including those parentheses. It may not look pretty, but it will always give you the right precedence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if I always put the parentheses when I have || or && it might mess up with the way the filter should be processed. And it would ignore the parentheses that I explicitly added to the expression.

Comment: @Eric.M: I would *hope* it wouldn't mess with the way the filter should be processed. I'm not sure what you mean by "ignore the parentheses that I explicitly added to the expression" - the *compiler* will use those to work out how to create the expression tree to start with. Have you *tried* this and found it to not work?

Comment: Would an expression like `o => o.A == "A" || (o.X == "X" && x.Y == "Y")` turn into  `((A eq 'A') || ((X eq 'X') && (Y eq 'Y')))` or `((A eq 'A') || (X eq 'X')) && (Y eq 'Y')?`. 'cause the first is the right one. It's horrible but it would work. I actually would like to identify the parentheses and add them if necessary, it would be a lot better.

Comment: And, since it's odata and it goes as a parameter in an Url, If I could have less characters, It would be better, since the filter might be long and I wouldn't want to add a book to the url.

Comment: @Eric.M: I'd expect it to turn into the first one - can't you just test it though? If you want to reduce the number of characters, you would need to write code to work out whether the representation without the brackets would be the same as the representation with the brackets. That's likely to be quite a lot of work...

Comment: Hmm, I see. I'm gonna test it and I'll post the result here.